# SIMPER (R) getting Error in seq_len(min(which(z >= 0.7))) :

Tags: r, vegan

I'm currently trying to run the SIMPER {vegan} function to a matrix that has NAs in it and currently can not be turn into 0s.

I'm getting:

```
Error in seq_len(min(which(z >= 0.7))) : 
argument must be coercible to non-negative integer
In addition: Warning message:
In min(which(z >= 0.7)) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
```

Is there a way to do it or I have to transform the data?

Thanks,
Pedro L.

Comment: Post your matrix or a reproducible example. We cannot know for sure what problem you are running in to without having knowledge of your data matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I solved your problem, although read the FAQ of how to post reproducible questions.

The problem you have is basically that nothing in your data, `z`, is fulfilling "`>= 0.7`" , therefore you are returned with `integer(0)`. That is basically what the error message: "`In min(which(tg >= 0.7)) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf"` refers to.

The first error message is due to you trying to calculate: "`seq_len(integer(0))`" which returns: "`Error in seq_len(min(which(tg >= 0.7))) : argument must be coercible to non-negative integer`".

Reproducible data:

```
tg<-matrix(data=seq(0.01,0.25,0.01),5,5)
seq_len(min(which(tg>=0.7)))
```

So the solution is: check your matrix "z" and the results from it by dividing the expression `seq_len(min(which(tg>=0.7)))` in different parts. First run `which(tg>=0.7)` , then `min(which(tg>=0.7))` and so on. This is useful for troubleshooting codes in general.

Good luck!